# noSuchMethodError: '[]' dynamic call of null Receive: null Argument[0]

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I'm an amateur flutter mobile app developer, I am trying to display data from my database in my app but I am getting the above error

> noSuchMethodError: '[]' dynamic call of null Receive: null Argument[0]

I tried to correct and I have searched a lot but without success.
i really need help please. Thanks.

**model.dart**

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final String nom;
  final String mail;
  final String pass;

  User(
      {required this.id,
      required this.nom,
      required this.mail,
      required this.pass});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
        id: json['id'],
        nom: json['nom'],
        mail: json['mail'],
        pass: json['pass']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'nom': nom, 'mail': mail, 'pass': pass};
}

class Env {
  static String urlUser =
      "https://tops-rifle.000webhostapp.com/planning/getPost.php";
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/models/model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Accueil extends StatefulWidget {
  const Accueil({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AccueilState createState() => _AccueilState();
}

class _AccueilState extends State<Accueil> {
  late Future<List<User>> user;
  final userListKey = GlobalKey<_AccueilState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = getUserList();
  }

  Future<List<User>> getUserList() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Env.urlUser));
    final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    debugPrint(items);
    List<User> user = items.map<User>((json) {
      return User.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();

    return user;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //key: userListKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shadowColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text("Kaomini",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, color: Colors.blue)),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: user,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          /*if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }*/
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var data = snapshot.data[index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.view_list),
                    title: Text(
                      data.nom,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**php**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
while($a = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $result[] = $a;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you are getting when just trying to print snapshot?

Comment: In which line the error occured?

Comment: I have no display

Comment: @Code Master accueil.dart, line 54:41

Comment: Can you please paste the code of accueil.dart?

Comment: @CodeMaster now error is XMLHttpRequest error. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

@CodeMaster the **accueil.dart** code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/models/model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Accueil extends StatefulWidget {
  const Accueil({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AccueilState createState() => _AccueilState();
}

class _AccueilState extends State<Accueil> {
  late Future<List<User>> user;
  final userListKey = GlobalKey<_AccueilState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = getUserList();
    //setState(() {});
  }

  Future<List<User>> getUserList() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.https("tops-rifle.000webhostapp.com/planning/getPost.php", ""));
    final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    debugPrint(items);
    List<User> user = items.map<User>((json) {
      return User.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();

    return user;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //key: userListKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shadowColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text("Kaomini",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, color: Colors.blue)),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: user,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          debugPrint(snapshot.data.toString());
          debugPrint(getUserList().toString());
          /*if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }*/
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var data = snapshot.data![index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.view_list),
                    title: Text(
                      data.nom,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```